# Check if the PWA is already installed

Tags: installation, progressive-web-apps

If my PWA isn't installed on the user's system yet, I want to prompt the user to install it. It seems that the beforeinstallprompt event fires when a PWA hasn't been installed yet, but it only works in Chrome and Edge. Is there a cross browser solution?